# Указать компилятору protobuf путь к googleapis

Tags: golang, google-protobuf

Как указать компилятору protobuf путь к файлу google/api/annotations.proto или как правильно установить https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/tree/master/google/api?
Данный код:

```
import "google/api/annotations.proto";
```

Вызывает следующую ошибку:

```
 Import "google/api/annotations.proto" was not found or had errors
```

Компилирую при помощи команды:

```
protoc -I $MYPATH/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2/protoc-gen-openapiv2/options -I . --grpc-gateway_out . \
    --grpc-gateway_opt logtostderr=true \
    --grpc-gateway_opt paths=source_relative \
    service.proto
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо [загрузить проект](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis), либо с помощью команды:

```
go install github.com/googleapis/googleapis@latest
```

, либо с помощью:

```
git clone https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis
```

Далее необходимо указать путь до загруженного проекта. Например, я скачал с помощью `git clone` в ту же директорию, где лежит мой service.proto.

```
protoc -I googleapis/ -I . --grpc-gateway_out . \
--grpc-gateway_opt logtostderr=true \
--grpc-gateway_opt paths=source_relative \
service.proto
```

То же самое, если вы загрузили с помощью go get:

```
protoc -I $GOPATH/pkg/mod/github.com/googleapis/googleapis@<version>/ -I . --grpc-gateway_out . \
--grpc-gateway_opt logtostderr=true \
--grpc-gateway_opt paths=source_relative \
service.proto
```

Предполагаю, что вы пытаетесь развернуть reverse proxy. Возможно вам поможет [инструкция по генерации](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway#usage)